google signin error: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, h2.b: 10: , null, null)
i am trying to sign in to google in my app but it gives me this error, the error is only present in production code and works just fine in debugging or the emulator:
Non-fatal Exception: io.flutter.plugins.firebase.crashlytics.FlutterError: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, h2.b: 10: , null, null)
       at GoogleSignInApi.signIn(messages.g.dart:221)
       at GoogleSignInAndroid._signInUserDataFromChannelData(google_sign_in_android.dart:111)
       at GoogleSignIn._callMethod(google_sign_in.dart:274)
       at GoogleSignIn.signIn.isCanceled(google_sign_in.dart:408)

google signin:
final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
    scopes: [
      'email',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata',
    ],
  );

triggered function:
Future<void> logInWithGoogle(BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      final GoogleSignInAccount? account = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
      if (account == null) {
        debugPrint('Google Sign-In aborted by user.');
        return;
      }

      _email = account.email;

      appConfigBox.put('email', _email);

      notifyListeners();
      debugPrint('User logged in: $_email');
    } catch (e, stackTrace) {
      debugPrint('Failed to sign in to Google: $e');
      if (context.mounted) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
            .showSnackBar(appSnackBar('Failed To Sign In To Google'));
      }
      FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(e, stackTrace);
    }
  }

i double checked my signing keys and made sure they are correct, i double checked i have added the dependencies correctly, neither fixed the issue.
